Make sure script waits for await fetch result before continuing
I need to make a post request so I'm using the fetch request below.
async function record(recording_url, options) {
    const recording_outcome = await fetch (recording_url, options);
    const outcome = await recording_outcome.json();

    return outcome;
}


let outcome = record(recording_url, options);
let record_div = document.getElementById("record_creation");
let record_saved = document.createElement("p");
record_saved.innerText = result.outcome;

However I've found the it doesn't wait and the rest of the script keeps running and when adding to the innertext it prints a promise object. Do I need to restructure this or is there a sensible way to make sure it waits for the result?
I did try adding a promise like in the example below but that didn't work as expected.
outcome.then(function(result){
   record_saved.innerText = result.outcome;
});


Why didn't the promise work as expected? That is the expected behavior. As long as you don't use await in front of the record function call, it will return a Promise, not the awaited result.

That might be a mismatch in my expectations then. I was expecting await recording_outcome.json() to wait for json to arrive before returning.

await recording_outcome.json() should do just that. However, record() is an async function, so you will need to await it when you call it: let outcome = await record(recording_url,options);

@Jcarty-Pinner, I have posted my answer. give it a try. And if you want to stick to async/await format to resolve the issue then check this link where I have answered a exactly same answer with detailed explanation. Please check it
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78673780/21210375

You are making your code unnecessarily complex. Instead try this simple approach.
let record_div = document.getElementById("record_creation"); //not mentioned in question what it supposed to do
let record_saved = document.createElement("p");

//call the fetch API directly
fetch(recording_url, options)  //pass the required parameter
      .then(response => {
          // Check if the request was successful
          if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
          }
          //Parse the response as JSON
          return response.json()
       })
      .then(data => {
         console.log(data) //check the structure of the returned data
         record_saved.innerText = data; //do your things
       })
      .catch(error => {
        // Handle any errors that occurred during the fetch
        console.error('Fetch error:', error);
       }); 

Try this, it will work.

As Sjoertjuh mentioned, the following code snippet will give you the data returned from the promise:
outcome.then(function (result) {
  record_saved.innerText = result.outcome;
});

I'm unsure of what you are trying to accomplish next though which may be causing some confusion? Are you trying to display this text on your page? If so, you will need to insert the created p tag somewhere in the DOM like so:
let record_div = document.getElementById("record_creation");
let record_saved = document.createElement("p");
record_div.insertBefore(record_saved, null);

It would also help to put a console.log tracer inside your returned promise logic like this:
outcome.then(function (result) {
  console.log(result)
  record_saved.innerText = result.outcome;
});

Open up your developer tools and inspect the result in your console log to make sure you are accessing the correct data.

You have to mention the correct use of async/await. Is unclear.
